# Get the date values from previous rows if not available in current

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the logic/Query for the below situation in SQL Server:

```
Last Updated                              Time
2018-06-21 23:09:21.947                 21-06-2018
2018-06-21 23:09:21.947                 23:09
2018-06-22 00:14:02.877                 23:15
2018-06-22 00:29:13.660                 22-06-2018
2018-06-22 00:29:13.660                 23:15
2018-06-22 00:41:20.773                 23-06-2018
2018-06-22 00:41:20.773                 23:20
2018-06-22 02:58:44.160                 23:22
2018-06-22 02:59:40.097                 23:25
2018-06-22 03:00:07.770                 23:28
```

I've the data as above and I want to get as below:

```
Last Updated                            Time    Time/Date
2018-06-21 23:09:21.947            21-06-2018   21-06-2018 23:09
2018-06-22 00:14:02.877               23:15     21-06-2018 23:15
2018-06-22 00:29:13.660              22-06-2018 22-06-2018 23:15
2018-06-22 00:41:20.773              23-06-2018 23-06-2018 23:20
2018-06-22 02:58:44.160                 23:22   23-06-2018 23:22
2018-06-22 02:59:40.097                  23:25  23-06-2018 23:25
2018-06-22 03:00:07.770                 23:28   23-06-2018 23:28
```

AS above, need to get the Date/time column, if there is no date get the previous date based on last updated column.
My first question, Cheers!!

Comment: Is Time a VARCHAR column?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, Sir its VARCHAR.

Comment: why the second row in time is  `23:15`

Comment: Also post the schema  if you have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely based on your data. So you may want to change it accordingly.

```
declare @RawData as Table
(
    LastUpdate DateTime,
    Time Varchar(20)
)

declare @Data as Table
(
    RowId int,
    LastUpdate DateTime,
    Time Varchar(20)
)

declare @FinalData as Table
(
    LastUpdate DateTime,
    Time Varchar(20),
    [DateTime] DateTime 
)

Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-21 23:09:21.947','21-06-2018')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-21 23:09:21.947','23:09')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 00:14:02.877','23:15')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 00:29:13.660','22-06-2018')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 00:29:13.660','23:15')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 00:41:20.773','23-06-2018')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 00:41:20.773','23:20')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 02:58:44.160','23:22')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 02:59:40.097','23:25')
Insert into @RawData values ('2018-06-22 03:00:07.770','23:28')

insert into @Data
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastUpdate ASC), * from @RawData 

Declare @Count INT
SET @Count = (Select count(*) from @Data)

DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=@Count)
BEGIN
    Declare @Date varchar(10)
    Declare @FinalDate varchar(10)

    if((Select Len(trim(time)) from @data where RowId = @intFlag) =10)
    Begin
        SET @Date = (Select Convert(date, time, 104) from @data where RowId = @intFlag)
    end
    else
    Begin 
        if((select Len(trim(time)) from @Data where RowID = @intFlag -1 ) = 10)
        Begin
            insert into @FinalData
            Select LastUpdate, time, Convert(Datetime,@Date + ' ' + time) from @data where RowID = @intFlag
        End
        else
        Begin
            insert into @FinalData
            Select LastUpdate, time, Convert(Datetime,@Date + ' ' + time) from @data where RowID = @intFlag
        End

    End 
    SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END

Select * from @FinalData

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using set-based operations.  Here is one method:

```
select t1.last_updated, t1.time,
       (t2.time + ' ' + t1.time) as time_date     
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.time like '%-%-%'
            t2.last_updated <= t.last_updated
      order by t2.last_updated desc
     ) t2
where time like '%:%'
group by last_updated;
```